# Philippine Airlines - power supply in economy

Tags: air-travel, power, seating, philippine-airlines

Does anyone know if the Economy seats on Philippine Airlines flights (777) have in-seat power supply?

Comment: For this sort of thing, consult [SeatGuru](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Philippine_Airlines/information.php) or [SeatExpert](http://seatexpert.com/).

Answer (score 3):

They do not have in-seat power in economy class: http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Philippine_Airlines/Philippine_Airlines_Boeing_777-300ER.php

Comment: Note, this answer is several years old and may well be out of date.

Comment: The link to seat guru still supports the statement in the answer.